# Firebase chat issue - two messages at the same time

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, firebase

I'm new here and I just can't figure how to solve this:

```
func sendMessage(msgText : String) {
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    let myRootRef = Firebase(url:"https://boiling-heat-3478.firebaseio.com/")
    self.messageCount = String(Int(self.messageCount)!+1)
    let messagesRef = myRootRef.childByAppendingPath("messages")
    let messageIDRef = messagesRef.childByAppendingPath(self.messageCount)
    let messageInfo = ["Text": self.messageText.text!, "SenderID": defaults.objectForKey("userID") as! String]
    messageIDRef.updateChildValues(messageInfo)
}
```

On view did load:

```
let myRootRef = Firebase(url:"https://boiling-heat-3478.firebaseio.com/")
    let messagesRef = myRootRef.childByAppendingPath("messages")
    let ref1 = Firebase(url: String(messagesRef))
    // Attach a closure to read the data at our posts reference
    ref1.queryOrderedByKey().queryStartingAtValue(self.messageCount).observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in


        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){

        let path = String(snapshot.ref)
        let parts = path.characters.split("/")

        if(Int(self.messageCount) < Int(String(parts.last!))){ self.messageCount = String(Int(self.messageCount)!+1) }

        let messageText = snapshot.value.objectForKey("Text") as! String
        let senderNameAge = snapshot.value.objectForKey("SenderID") as! String
        let msg = Message(nameAge: senderNameAge, image: nil, text: messageText)
        self.messages.append(msg)

        self.messageTableView.reloadData()
        }
    }, withCancelBlock: { error in
            print(error.description)
    })
```

Well, this is working fine. I can chat with 1 person and see replies in real-time, but when I try to send like "aaaa" from person 1 to 2 and "bbbb" from person 2 to 1: message "aaaa" shows only on person 1 screen and "bbbb" on person 2.
Also, I can see on firebase that one of those messages replaced the other on the same destination! How can I avoid or solve this? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a problem by trying to use a count to index your messages.

The [Firebase documentation explicitly warns against using arrays](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/understanding-data.html#section-arrays-in-firebase), since (as you're finding out) it is difficult to keep the message count in sync between multiple clients.

Instead of keeping the count synchronized between clients, you can simply call [`childByAutoId`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios-api/Classes/Firebase.html#//api/name/childByAutoId) on a `Firebase` reference to generate a new child ID that is guaranteed to be unique and always incrementing.

```
let messagesRef = myRootRef.childByAppendingPath("messages")
let messageIDRef = messagesRef.childByAutoId()
let messageInfo = ["Text": self.messageText.text!, "SenderID": defaults.objectForKey("userID") as! String]
messageIDRef.updateChildValues(messageInfo)
```

See [this section of the documentation for more information and examples](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/saving-data.html#section-lists).

Also see this [example of a chat app written in Swift](https://github.com/firebase/ios-swift-chat-example), that you can use for inspiration.